# Program is returning 0

Tags: python

I am currently tackling problem 23 on Project Euler and my code keeps returning nothing when I am trying to compare a set of numbers from 1 - 28123 and a list of numbers that contain all the possible combinations of 2 abundant numbers below 28123. So that I can remove them later, apologies for the inefficient code, any comments of efficiency would be very appreciated.

All I know is that I'm relatively confident the code 'lisp' and before should be correct. Cheers!

```
import itertools

success = []
flatten_iter = itertools.chain.from_iterable


def factors(n):
    return set(flatten_iter((i, n//i)
                            for i in range(1, int(n**0.5)+1) if n % i == 0))

for x in range(1, 28124):
    if (sum(list(factors(x))) - x) > x:
        success.append(x)

lisp = []
for x in success:
    lisp.append(2 * x)

numbers = []
for x in range(1, 28124):
    numbers.append(x)

prefinal = [x + y for x in success for y in success]
zipped = zip(prefinal, lisp)
final = set(zipped).intersection(numbers)

print(final)
```

Comment: Have you tried basic debugging? E.g., printing out intermediate variables and such? That can quickly tell you where things go wrong.

Comment: `zipped` elements correspond to tuple, `numbers` to simple integer. So the intersection between them will always be empty.

Comment: I'd also suggest replacing the `for` loops with list comprehensions: `success = [ x for x in range(1, 28124) if sum(list(factors(x))) > 2*x ]`, `lisp = [2* x for x in success]` and `numbers = list(range(1, 28124))`.

Comment: THank you! I have solved it.